# ReactJS + Rsuite 3 How to include the dark theme file?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a project made with `create-react-app`. I installed `rsuite` with `npm install rsuite`.

I'm following the documentation: https://rsuitejs.com/en/guide/themes

I would like to use the dark theme in my project, but I can't find the following file:

`@import '~rsuite/dist/styles/rsuite-dark.css';`

The file I'm currently including is: `import 'rsuite/dist/styles/rsuite.min.css';`

> Please fork this example, reproduce the problem you are issue.
>   https://codesandbox.io/s/5vq6zo2z5l

In the sandbox it seems to work fine. Actually the import they included in the sandbox doesn't work (`import "rsuite/dist/styles/rsuite.min.css";`) but if you replace it with import `import 'rsuite/dist/styles/rsuite-dark.css';` it works.

Does anyone know what steps I have to follow in order to include the dark theme css file?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out: I just needed to update to the last version (4.0.0).

To update all packages to the last version you can use this commands:

> npm i -g npm-check-updates
>
> ncu -u
>
> npm install